# How to add create our custom filter in view drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I am very new to drupal. I am using drupal 7. I have created a view and it is working fine. What i need to create my own custom filter in drupal view.I need to create my own custom filter in views. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hook available i.e.  hook_views_data_alter() It will help you to create custom filter type. Below us the code

```
function my_module_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['node']['title_count']['title'] = 'Title word count';
  $data['node']['title_count']['help'] = 'Count the number of words in titles.';
  $data['node']['title_count']['filter']['handler'] = 'my_module_handler_filter_field_count';
}
```

Here my module name is my_module.

Here custom filter is being display in the filter list. 
Hope it will help you.
 [image]